# Obtener el resultado de una consulta y mediante ese resultado hacer un like a otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Buenos días.
Necesito mezclar ambas consultas en una

```
SELECT nombre_categoria from tablacategorias where id_categoria=1;
select * from videos A where A.categorias;
```

Lo que intento es: En la "tablacategorias" quiero que me devuelva el nombre de la categoria segun el id que le paso.  Una vez que tenga el "nombre de la categoría" quiero obtener de la tabla "videos" todos los videos que tengan esa categoría.

Necesito que sea mediante LIKE, ya que un video puede tener mas de una categoría. En mi caso las categorias van en un mismo campo separadas por comas.
Ejemplo: Drama, comedia, acción

El resultado sería una cosa parecida a esta:

```
select * from videos A where A.categorias like '%(SELECT nombre_categoria from tablacategorias where id_categoria=1)%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes unirla en una sola haciendo un `JOIN` donde la condicion sea el `like`, sería algo así:

```
select A.* from videos
join tablacategoria tCat on A.categorias like 
'%' + tCat.nombre_categoria + '%' 
where tCat.id_categoria=1
```

Comment: Genial,  muchísimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba. Eres un Crack!!

Comment: Puede usar la función [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) para concatenar: `... like CONCAT('%', tCat.nombre_categoria, '%') ...`.